# How get the value of disabled ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, coded-ui-tests

i have a lot of trouble with my CUIT. I want to test my window with data from database. The window is so constructed that some fields are deactivated so that the user can not change the values. The ComboBox gets a value, but in CUIT I can not read this value, because the control is not enabled. That's why I can not read properties of control right, SelectedIndex is f.e. always -1. Is there any way to find the text of ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with `WpfComboBox`, you can obtain all items of the combobox by getting the property `Items`. It returns you basically `UITestControlCollection` and you can enumerate through its elements:

```
foreach (UITestControl uiTestControl in yourUiTestControlCollection)
{
    string name = uiTestControl.FriendlyName;
}
```

or similarly by using lambda-expressions.

In this case it does not matter which item is selected and in which state (`Enabled = true/false;`) the combobox is.

However, it might not help if your combobox loads all the items somehow dynamically when changing its state to enabled. Then you will have to find another test scenario to make the combobox enabled before you analyze it with your test method.

Hope it will help.